# Password product one URL

Tags: htaccess

I am trying to password protect one URL on a Magento site.

I have my .htpasswd setup

I have tried using the  directive - NO LUCK. I also tried the following:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/url-name require_auth=true
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'By Invitation Only'
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/path/.htpasswd

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

But when I do the above it ends up doing the entire site. I am putting everything right before the  tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this in .htaccess. You define the authentication, so it applies. You are doing this at the Directory level, so you can't use location here.

If you do not have access to the apache main configuration, then I would use authentication in php and use a rewrite rule to match the url and rewrite it to that file.

But once you are down that path you may as well extend the Magento product class to an authenticated product. That way you can implement it without worrying about server implementation and you can use customer groups to implement different "preview" campaigns that can run along side each other.